# How to make multiple files on an internal storage

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-file

Hey this might seem like a silly question but how can I make multiple file in intrnal storage with out my having to spam

```
   f = new File(context.getFilesDir(),filename);
```

when I want to make a file every time the user touchs the screen.I have tryed to have it were file name has a number at the end so it different when I create the file but the program always resorts back to the orginal file  "name0" instead of "name1" even when the logs say it should say 1

```
  String filename = "name"+num;
```

what do i have to change for the program  to generate a new file of data each time the user touchs the screen?

---

Ontouch method for the panel class

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 mainactivity.setvalue(newvalue);
            mElements.add(new Element(getResources(),(int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY(),this.getContext()));
            Log.v("Gesture", "is newvalue: "+newvalue);   
                newvalue++;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
```

---

Elements class

```
public Element(Resources res, int x, int y,Context context) {
  location2 =item3;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, location2);
    mX = x - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    mY = y - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); 
     byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); 
     writeBitmap(byteArray, context);
     writemX(mX,context);
     writemY(mY,context);
     Log.v("Element", "num: "+num);
    num++;

}
```

---

writeX method

```
public void writemX(int x,Context context){
        value=getvalue();
        Log.v("main", "made it to method writeX" );
        Log.v("main", "value before= "+getvalue());         
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(),postionX);

            try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    objectwrite = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    objectwrite.writeByte(x);
        fos.close(); 
     Log.v("main", "file was  made File ");

     }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("main", "file was not made File not found ");

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("main", "file was not made File IOException ");
    }

public int  getvalue(){
        Log.v("main", "getvale value = "+value);
        return(value);
    }

    public void setvalue(int newvalue){
        value=newvalue;
        Log.v("main", "setvale value = "+value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I think:

```
new Element(---,---,---,this.getContext());
```

should be

```
new Element(---,---,---,YourActivity.this);
```

Also I don't think creating so many files like this is going to work out very well even if you manage to get past the problem you are currently having. Manipulating files is fairly slow in terms of activities that computers are capable of. the onTouch() method gets callbacks very very fast.

What problem are you trying to solve by creating so many files? What ever data it is you are trying to store there is almost certainly a better means to store it than creating so many files with incrementing names.

Comment: I'm trying to make make a program that place a picture where you touched the screen and I want it so they can save what they done.I'm trying to solve the problem I had when I tried to save the element object.It wouldn't save because I had stuff in element that wasn't meant to be serialized like bitmap and matrix.So I'm trying get around that by save the content of the object so the bitmap and the location in a file and re-assemble it when it opened.In short i need lot of file because each image would need a separate file i think